# SSRS 2008 Report Builder: Conditionally Turning off Tablix Filters

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Is it possible to turn off Tablix filters based on which parameter is selected? I want my data to be filtered if one value is null but I want my data NOT to be filtered if a different value is null. User enters in Start Date, End Date and Shift OR VCN. All 4 parameters can be set to null. The first 3 parameters find the averages for a range of values. So I have Tablix filters set up to remove outliers from the data. For example it only allows numbers within a certain range. However, when the user enters a VCN, it will pull up a single record so I do not want any data filtered even if it is an outlier because then sometimes it will return no values.

Comment: Can you give a little more info?

Comment: User enters in Start Date, End Date and Shift OR VCN. All 4 parameters can be set to null. The first 3 parameters find the averages for a range of values. So I have Tablix filters set up to remove outliers from the data. However, when the user enters a VCN, it will pull up a single record so I do not want any data filtered even if it is an outlier because then sometimes it will return no values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can with this little work around.

1. Select the field to be filtered in the filter option on the tablix, e.g. `[Field1]`.
2. Set the operator to `=`.
3. In the value option set an expression similar to the below that will make the filter null and void if there is nothing set in the paramater of concern:

   ```
   =IIf(IsNothing(Parameter!MyPar1.Value), Field!Field1.Value, Parameter!MyPar1.Value)
   ```

---

After the comment if you were to assume the `VCN` parameter was null only if the `VCN` filter was intented, then i would apply the following filters to the tablix.

For the **date** filter:

- Field: `[Date]`
- Operator: `>=`
- Formula: `=IIf(IsNothing(Parameter!VCN.Value), Parameter!StartDate.Value, Field!Date.Value)`

Second **date** filter:

- Field: `[Date]`
- Operator: `<=`
- Formula: `=IIf(IsNothing(Parameter!VCN.Value), Parameter!EndDate.Value, Field!Date.Value)`

For the **shift** filter:

- Field: `[Shift]`
- Operator: `=`
- Formula: `=IIf(IsNothing(Parameter!VCN.Value), Parameter!Shift.Value, Field!Shift.Value)`

For the **VCN** filter:

- Field: `[VCN]`
- Operator: `=`
- Formula: `=IIf(IsNothing(Parameter!VCN.Value), Field!VCN.Value, Parameter!VCN.Value)`

Comment: My situation is that for each table I have 3 filters. My user enters in start date, end date, and shift OR they can just enter in VCN number. If they enter in VCN number I want the filters to shut off. I allow the user to set the others to null then they enter in the VCN #. How can I apply your solution to my situation?

Answer (score 0):

I would redesign your filters to return a Boolean and set the value to True.  Then within the Filter Expression you can use the Iif function to check your Parameter and return True (include) or False (exclude).

This is generally a better strategy for even simple Filters as data type conversions etc are bizarre and fickle.

Answer (score 0):

I did a work around and just created a new table instead, and then hid my other tables based upon an expression.